# Launcher in Unity opens application in another icon

Tags: unity, launcher

I have an application locked to my launcher. Whenever I click on it or use the normal `Exec=.....` in the `.desktop`, it works perfectly. I have recently added a quicklist option in the launcher. Whenever I select this option, it opens the application, but not within the launcher icon. It will open its own instance further down on the launcher. It's not the biggest deal in the world, but I would just prefer to have it open natively in the launcher. Any thoughts?

If a video would help, I can record one.

Comment: This 5+ year old unanswered question is about Ubuntu 12.04 which is EOL. After upgrading to Ubuntu 12.10 OP switched to Arch Linux (according to his Bio). As such this problem (which should arguably a feature request in the first place) cannot be solved. VTC as `not reproducible`.